# How to make POST request in Node.Js Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make POST request for OTP using Node.Js Express. Below is the code for making post request using `request` but I want to make post request using Express.

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://d7-verify.p.rapidapi.com/send',
  headers: {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  authorization: 'undefined',
  'x-rapidapi-key': 'e47df3d7e5msh868bdee0049d425p19',
  'x-rapidapi-host': 'd7-verify.p.rapidapi.com',
  useQueryString: true
 },
 body: {
 expiry: 900,
 message: 'Your otp code is {code}',
 mobile: 971562316353,
 sender_id: 'SMSInfo'
 },
 json: true
};

 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 if (error) throw new Error(error);

 console.log(body);
});
```

How can I make above request in Express framework?

Comment: Express.js is about receiving requests

Comment: How can I convert above request into express post request.

Comment: Do you want to receive such requests using Express.js in your backend Node.js serivce?

Comment: Yes exactly please let me know .

Answer (score 0):

Express, is a back end web application framework for Node.js. To receive such requests using Express.js the following code will be helpful

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// POST method route
app.post('/sendotp', function (req, res) {

    //Generate OTP
    var otp=Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);

    //Get Mobile number from response body
    var mobile=req.body.mobile;

    //Then send OTP to respective mobile number

    // send sucess message to use
    res.send('OTP Sent Successfully')
  })
```

Comment: How can I transfrom my code into this one.